# Cannot view .gitignore file in Mac

Tags: git, shell, gitignore, ls

I cannot view the .gitignore file in Mac via ls. But vi is able to open it and edit. Cannot add the file to  git and it’s not working either. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: what is MAC here?

Comment: Sorry I meant Apple terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files starting with `.` are considered "hidden" in Unix systems such as OSX. Use `ls -a` to view them.

Comment: Thanks, is there a setting I need to change it to normal

Comment: No. It's the default behaviour for all files starting with `.`. if you always want `ls` to show all files, you could `alias ls ls -a`